# Role based authorization not working in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

In my login action I am creating role as follows:

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists("Customer"))
{
     Roles.CreateRole("Customer");
     Roles.AddUserToRole("UserName", "Customer");
}
```

After successful login I am redirecting to dashboard where I authorize the user at controller level:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Customer")]
public class DashBoardController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The above controller is supposed to be accessed by users with roles **Admin** or **Customer**

**In My Web.config:**

```
<system.web>    
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication>
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

**Problem:**
After login and role creation when I redirected to the dashboard gives me error:

1. You do not have permission to view this directory or page
2. I am not getting redirected to login page after failed
   authentication.

Why my authorization is getting failed and after failing why I am not redirected to login page?

**Note:** Login and dashboard resides in two different projects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a custom role provider?

Comment: No it is not a custom role provider.